# Is it possible to "await yield return DoSomethingAsync()"

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0, iasyncenumerable

Are regular iterator blocks (i.e. "yield return") incompatible with "async" and "await"?

This gives a good idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> Method(String [] Strs)
{
    // I want to compose the single result to the final result, so I use the SelectMany
    var finalResult = UrlStrings.SelectMany(link =>   //i have an Urlstring Collection 
                   await UrlString.DownLoadHtmlAsync()  //download single result; DownLoadHtmlAsync method will Download the url's html code 
              );
     return finalResult;
}
```

However, I get a compiler error citing "unable to load message string from resources".

Here is another attempt:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> Method(String [] Strs)
{
    foreach(var str in strs)
    {
        yield return await DoSomethingAsync( str)
    }
}
```

But again, the compiler returns an error: "unable to load message string from resources".

---

Here is the real programming code in my project

This is very useful when I have an List Task,that task can be download HTML from a URL
and I use the syntax "yield return await task", the result is I want `IEnumerable<Foo>`.  I don't want write this code:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<String>> DownLoadAllURL(String [] Strs)
{
    List<Foo> htmls= new ...
    foreach(var str in strs)
    {
        var html= await DownLoadHtmlAsync( str)
        htmls.Add(item)
    }
    return htmls;
}
```

But it seems that I have to.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question isn't particularly clear, you should elaborate on what it is exactly that you wish to do - its difficult to determine what it is you wish to do from just a code sample alone.

Comment: The [Ix_Experimental-Async NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ix_Experimental-Async) includes "asynchronous enumerators" complete with LINQ support. They use the `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` type as defined by Arne.

Comment: @StephenCleary that package has been delisted. Since this was ages ago & authored by MS's rxteam, do you know if that got rolled into RX?

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus: Looks like it [lives on as Ix-Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Async/).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

What you are describing can be accomplished with the `Task.WhenAll` method. Notice how the code turns into a simple one-liner. What happens is that each individual url begins downloading and then `WhenAll` is used combine those operations into a single `Task` which can be awaited.

```
Task<IEnumerable<string>> DownLoadAllUrls(string[] urls)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(from url in urls select DownloadHtmlAsync(url));
}
```

Comment: async/await are not needed in this case. Just remove `async` from the method and do `return Task.WhenAll` directly.

Comment: @luiscubal: Yep, fixed.

Comment: The last line can be written more succinctly as `urls.Select(DownloadHtmlAsync)`

Comment: This turned out to be the exact problem I was facing (lazily downloading strings from a series of URIs). Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of `Is it possible to await yield?`  You just found a work-around for this one use-case.  Didn't answer the general question.

Comment: Have you actually tested this code in an IDE? I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string[]>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'`.

Comment: A succinct solution if the result doesn't need to be an `IEnumerable` is just `Task<string[]> DownloadAllUrls(string[] urls) => Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(DownloadHtmlAsync));`

Comment: I would be inclined to return `Task<string[]>` as this would indicate that you are no longer returning an iterator with deferred execution ie. all of the URLs are being downloaded.

Comment: For a 2022 update : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53291088/5466477

Answer (score 83):

**tl;dr** Iterators as implemented with yield are a blocking construct, so as of right now await and yield are incompatible.

**Long** Because iterating over an `IEnumerable` is a blocking operation, calling a method marked as `async` will still execute it in a blocking manner, since it has to wait for that operation to finish.

```
async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> Method(String [] Strs)
{
  foreach(var str in strs)
  {
    yield return await DoSomethingAsync( str)
  }
}
```

The awaiting `Method` mixes meanings. Do you want to wait until the `Task` has an `IEnumerable` and then block on iterating over it? Or are you trying to await each value of the `IEnumerable`?

I assume the second is the desired behavior and in that case the existing Iterator semantics will not work. The `IEnumerator<T>` interface is basically

```
public interface IEnumerator<T>
  T Current;
  bool MoveNext();
}
```

I'm ignoring `Reset()` since it makes no sense for a sequence of asynchronous results. But what you would need is something like this:

```
public interface IAsyncEnumerator<T>
  T Current;
  Task<bool> MoveNext();
}
```

Of course, `foreach` also won't work with this and you'd have to iterate manually like this:

```
var moveNext = await asyncEnumerator.MoveNext();
while(moveNext) {

  // get the value that was fetche asynchronously
  var v = asyncEnumerator.Current;

  // do something with that value

  // suspend current execution context until next value arrives or we are done
  moveNext = await asyncEnumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible that the next C# language version will add `foreach` support for your hypothetical `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`?

Comment: @Dai I think its very much in the pipeline. for C# 8.0/ Had read about it.

Comment: @Dai , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams .

Answer (score 81):

According to the new features at **C# 8.0** ([link#1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/) and [link#2](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1440/csharp-8-new-features)) we'll have `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` interface support that will allow to implement your second attempt. It will look like this:

```
async Task<Foo> DoSomethingAsync(string url)
{
    ...
}       
// producing IAsyncEnumerable<T>
async IAsyncEnumerable<Foo> DownLoadAllURL(string[] strs)
{
    foreach (string url in strs)
    {
        yield return await DoSomethingAsync(url);
    }
}
...
// using
await foreach (Foo foo in DownLoadAllURL(new string[] { "url1", "url2" }))
{
    Use(foo);
}
```

We can achieve the same behavior at **C# 5** but with a different semantics:

```
async Task<Foo> DoSomethingAsync(string url)
{
    ...
}
IEnumerable<Task<Foo>> DownLoadAllURL(string[] strs)
{
    foreach (string url in strs)
    {
        yield return DoSomethingAsync(url);
    }
}

// using
foreach (Task<Foo> task in DownLoadAllURL(new string[] { "url1", "url2" }))
{
    Foo foo = await task;
    Use(foo);
}
```

Brian Gideon's answer implies that the calling code will get asynchronously a collection of results that were obtained in parallel. The code above implies that the calling code will get results like from a stream one by one in asynchronous manner.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer, IAsyncEnumerable works for me

Answer (score 20):

I know that I'm too late with the answer, but here is another simple solution that can be achieved with this library:
GitHub: https://github.com/tyrotoxin/AsyncEnumerable
NuGet.org: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/
It's much simpler than Rx.

```
using System.Collections.Async;

static IAsyncEnumerable<string> ProduceItems(string[] urls)
{
  return new AsyncEnumerable<string>(async yield => {
    foreach (var url in urls) {
      var html = await UrlString.DownLoadHtmlAsync(url);
      await yield.ReturnAsync(html);
    }
  });
}

static async Task ConsumeItemsAsync(string[] urls)
{
  await ProduceItems(urls).ForEachAsync(async html => {
    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(html);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This feature will be available as of C# 8.0. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/

**From MSDN**

Async streams

The async/await feature of C# 5.0 lets you consume (and produce) asynchronous results in straightforward code, without callbacks:

```
async Task<int> GetBigResultAsync()
{
    var result = await GetResultAsync();
    if (result > 20) return result; 
    else return -1;
}
```

It is not so helpful if you want to consume (or produce) continuous streams of results, such as you might get from an IoT device or a cloud service. Async streams are there for that.

We introduce IAsyncEnumerable, which is exactly what you’d expect; an asynchronous version of IEnumerable. The language lets you await foreach over these to consume their elements, and yield return to them to produce elements.

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetBigResultsAsync()
{
    await foreach (var result in GetResultsAsync())
    {
        if (result > 20) yield return result; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There was a plan to do

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43

But currently it not possible

Updated: It was added in C# 8.0

Answer (score 1):

First of all, keep in mind that the Async stuff is not finished.  The C# team still has a long way to go before C# 5 is released.

That being said, I think you may want to gather the tasks that are being fired off in the `DownloadAllHtml` function in a different way.

For example, you can use something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Task<string>> DownloadAllUrl(string[] urls)
{
    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        yield return DownloadHtmlAsync(url);
    }
}

async Task<string> DownloadHtmlAsync(url)
{
    // Do your downloading here...
}
```

Not that the `DownloadAllUrl` function is **NOT** an async call.  But, you can have the async call implemented on another function (i.e. `DownloadHtmlAsync`).

The Task Parallel Library has the `.ContinueWhenAny` and [`.ContinueWhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall.aspx) functions.

That can be used like this:

```
var tasks = DownloadAllUrl(...);
var tasksArray = tasks.ToArray();
var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasksArray, completedTasks =>
{
    completedtask
});
continuation.RunSynchronously();
```

Comment: You can also have a 'header' (before the loop) if you define your method as async `Task<IEnumerable<Task<string>>> DownloadAllUrl`. Or, if you want 'footer' actions `IEnumerable<Task>`. E.g. https://gist.github.com/1184435

Comment: Now that the `async` stuff *is* finished and C# 5.0 *is* released, this *can* be updated.

Comment: I like this one, but how in this case foreach(var url in await GetUrls()) { yield return GetContent(url) }; I only found a way splitting in two methods.

Comment: The interesting thing about `DownloadAllUrl` method is that it is not quite correct to say that it isn't an async call. The thing that stops it from immediately running asynchronously is actually the `yield` keyword. As long you iterate through the returned `IEnumerable`, all the tasks will be started. Whether the tasks are being awaited on is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yield does not work with await, unfortunately. But this is what Rx is for. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh242985

Answer (score -1):

This solution works as expected. Note the `await Task.Run(() => enumerator.MoveNext())` part.

```
using (var enumerator = myEnumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (enumerator.Current != null)
        {
            //TODO: do something with enumerator.Current
        }

        var enumeratorClone = monitorsEnumerator;
        var hasNext = await Task.Run(() => enumeratorClone.MoveNext());
        if (!hasNext)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```