# Representing asynchronous sequences in C# 5

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How should you use C# 5's `async` to represent a sequence of asynchronous tasks? For example, if we wanted to download numbered files from a server and return each one as we get it, how can we implement a method such as this?

```
public async IEnumerable<File> DownloadPictures() {
    const string format = "http://example.com/files/{0}.png";
    for (int i = 0; i++; ) {
        yield return await DownloadFile(string.Format(format, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: @BoltClock http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156499(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Even though the framework is .NET 4.5, I believe the official version will be C# 5.  Much like the features associated with LINQ were added in C# 3, but the framework was .NET 3.5.

Comment: @JoshuaRodgers: I completely agree, but the only numbers MS has published so far are VS 11 and .Net 4.5 so I'll stick to those :)

Comment: Do you want to start all the downloads at once, or you want to do something smarter (similar to `Parallel.For()`)?

Comment: I've seen Eric Lippert himself refer to it as C# 5 on his blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx).  Although I haven't seen any officially published version numbers.

Also this is potentially a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061761/c-5-is-it-possible-to-await-yield-return-dosomethingasync

Comment: Anders has also said publically that the next version of the language will be called version 5 but I hasten to add that this name has not been *officially* announced. If you write a book about "C# 5" and we decide before ship that it should be called something else, don't complain to me!

Comment: We had a *huge* debate about this question that lasted a long time. Every option has different pros and cons -- you could have a coarse-grained `Task<IE<T>>` or a fine-grained `IE<Task<T>>`, or both with something crazy like `Task<IE<Task<T>>>`. The RX guys like `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`, as Stephen points out in his answer. I am actually not sure what the WinFX team settled on as the standard pattern for their library. I'll look into it.

Comment: @EricLippert, I had wondered why there doesn't seem to be anything to support something like this. The fact that there is no solution clearly superior to the others explains that. But I would welcome some library types that make working with asynchronous collections easier. (Which could support the different options.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me you want something very similar to [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), that uses `Task`s and `await`ing instead of blocking.

Specifically, something that you can add to without blocking or waiting. But when you try to remove an item when none is available at the moment, you can `await` until some item is available.

The public interface could look like this:

```
public class AsyncQueue<T>
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; }

    public Task<T> DequeueAsync();

    public void Enqueue(T item);

    public void FinishAdding();
}
```

`FinishAdding()` is necessary, so that we know when to end dequeuing.

With this, your code could look like this (`m_queue` is `AsyncQueue<File>`):

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => DownloadAndEnqueue(i))
    .ToArray();

Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t => m_queue.FinishAdding());

…

static async Task DownloadAndEnqueue(string url)
{
    m_queue.Enqueue(await DownloadFile(url));
}
```

It's not as nice as what you imagined could work, but it should work.

And the implementation of `AsyncQueue<T>`? There are two queues. One is for completed work, that hasn't been dequeued yet. The other is for `Task`s (actually, `TaskCompletionSource<T>`) that were already dequeued, but that don't have any result yet.

When you dequeue and there is some completed work in the queue, just return work from there (using `Task.FromResult()`). If the queue is empty, create new `Task`, add it to the other queue and return it.

When you enqueue some completed work and there are some `Task`s in the queue, remove one and finish it using the result we have now. If the `Task` queue is empty, add the work to the first queue.

With this, you can dequeue and enqueue as many times as you want, and it will work correctly. When you know there won't be any new work, call `FinishAdding()`. If there are any waiting `Task`s, they will throw an exception.

In other words:

```
public class AsyncQueue<T>
{
    private readonly object m_lock = new object();

    private bool m_finishedAdding = false;

    private readonly Queue<T> m_overflowQueue = new Queue<T>();

    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<T>> m_underflowQueue =
        new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<T>>();

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return m_finishedAdding && m_overflowQueue.Count == 0; }
    }

    public Task<T> DequeueAsync()
    {
        Task<T> result;
        lock (m_lock)
        {
            if (m_overflowQueue.Count > 0)
                result = Task.FromResult(m_overflowQueue.Dequeue());
            else if (!m_finishedAdding)
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
                m_underflowQueue.Enqueue(tcs);
                result = tcs.Task;
            }
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (m_lock)
        {
            if (m_finishedAdding)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            if (m_underflowQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var tcs = m_underflowQueue.Dequeue();
                tcs.SetResult(item);
            }
            else
                m_overflowQueue.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }

    public void FinishAdding()
    {
        lock (m_lock)
        {
            m_finishedAdding = true;

            while (m_underflowQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var tcs = m_underflowQueue.Dequeue();
                tcs.SetException(new InvalidOperationException());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to limit size of the work queue (and thus limiting producers, if they are too fast), you could make `Enqueue()` return `Task` too, which would require another queue.

Comment: Actually, awaiting task.WhenAll would defeat the purpose of this method because the AsyncQueue would only be returned after the tasks are finished. But this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for so thanks!

Comment: You're right and I didn't mean it like that. You should start that code on background and return the `AsyncQueue` immediately. The `WhenAll()` is there because of the necessary `FinishAdding()` that follows it.

Comment: I've edited the `await` out and now I believe it's good. Agreed?

Comment: Yeah, this works too. And, yeah, it's probably better to do it this way.

Comment: If somebody is reading this now: just use TPL Dataflow, it does exactly this (and much more).

Answer (score 5):

A true *sequence* doesn't work well directly with `async`/`await`, because tasks only return a single value. You need an actual enumerable type, such as `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` in [Ix-Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Async/) (or [AsyncEx](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/Nito.AsyncEx)). The design of `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` is described in [this Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Rx-Update-Async-support-IAsyncEnumerable-and-more-with-Jeff-and-Wes).

Comment: "The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore"

Comment: @WiebeTijsma: It is now named [Ix-Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Async/).

Comment: Thanks! I've taken the liberty to update the answer hope that's ok

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while, but I've written something to closely emulate "yield return" for async enumerables [here](http://idcomlog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15838#209781). No complicated code needed.

You use it like:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<File> DownloadPictures() {
    const string format = "http://example.com/files/{0}.png";
    return AsyncEnumerable.Create(async y =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i++; ) {
            await y.YieldReturn(await DownloadFile(string.Format(format, i)));
        }
    };
}
```

I normally avoid advertising my own code here but this is a clearly needed feature in C# 6.0, so I hope you find it useful in C# 5.0 if you're still stuck on this.

Answer (score -1):

If you only had a finite number of URLs, you could do this:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<File>> DownloadPictures()
    {
        const string format = "http://example.com/files/{0}.png";
        var urls = Enumerable.Range(0, 999).Select(i => String.Format(format, i));
        var tasks = urls.Select(u => DownloadFile(u));
        var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return await results;
    }
```

The key is to get a list of Tasks and then call Task.WhenAll on that list.

Comment: But now you can't process even a single task until every single file has been downloaded, and it forces you to bring the entire collection into memory, instead of being able to stream the results, and process them as they come in, greatly improving both the memory footprint as well as the speed of the application.  You even choose an example particularly poorly suited to this approach.  If you had a very small result set, and all items tended to be computed at about the same time, those problems aren't noticeable.

Comment: I missed the "return each one as we get it" part of the question. This article came up for a google search I was performing, and the answer I gave was for that.

Answer (score -1):

The benefit of `async` is the calling method can invoke several blocking operations in parallel and only block once the returned value is needed. This same capability is possible in this scenario with `yield/return` by using return type `IEnumerable<Task>`.

```
public IEnumerable<Task<File>> DownloadPictures() {
    const string format = "http://example.com/files/{0}.png";
    for (int i = 0; i++; ) {
        yield return DownloadFileAsync(string.Format(format, i));
    }
}
```

In a similar fashion to `async/await` the calling method can now continue to execute until it needs the next value at which point `await/.Result` can be called on the next task. The following extension method demonstrates this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Results<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks)
            yield return task.Result;
    }
```

If the calling method would like to ensure that all the `IEnumerable` `Task`s are created and running in parallel then an extension method such as the following may be beneficial (this, and the aforementioned method, are likely already in a standard lib):

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ResultsParallel<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks.ToArray())
            yield return task.Result;
    }
```

Notice how the responsibility for the concern of what runs in parallel is transferred to the calling method just as it was with `async/await`. In the event that there is concern regarding the creation of the `Task`s blocking, an extension method such as the following could be created:

```
    public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> ResultsAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        var startedTasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task<T>>();
        var writerTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                foreach (var task in tasks)
                {
                    startedTasks.Enqueue(task);
                }
            });
        writerTask.Start();

        var readerTask = new Task<IEnumerable<T>>(() =>
        {
            return ResultsSequential(startedTasks, () => writerTask.IsCompleted);
        });
        readerTask.Start();
        return readerTask;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> ResultsSequential<T>(ConcurrentQueue<Task<T>> tasks, Func<bool> isDone)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task<T> task;
            if (isDone.Invoke())
            {
                if (tasks.TryDequeue(out task))
                {
                    yield return task.Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield break;
                }
            } else if (tasks.TryDequeue(out task))
            {
                yield return task.Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

This implementation is not very efficient. An efficient implementation is [too large to fit in the margin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

Comment: The implementation of your last method is a single method call.  `return Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: Would WhenAll return the result of the first task before the last task is started?

Comment: I just took a look at how you implemented it and realized that it's just the same as your serial implementation except that you wrap it in an already completed task.  Nothing about it is asynchronous at all; it is entirely synchronous.  This is of course a limitation of its signature; given its signature it's *impossible* for it to yield the results of each operation asynchronously.  Your only options are to do everything synchronously, or only complete the task when you have all of the results.  I assumed you did the latter, because it's really the only sensible implementation.

Comment: @Servy Note that, as stated above, "In the event that there is concern regarding the creation of the Tasks blocking" that the implementation does work differently. Here are some unit tests that demonstrate that: https://gist.github.com/joshcodes/77fa505468bf1135d611 Please reconsider your down-vote.