# Use 'yield return' in async methods to achieve pipelining

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I'm building a UWP app that gets a list of files from a folder, do some processing on them, then get rid of the files.

This was working fine:

```
List<StorageFile> files;
public MainPage()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     files = new List<StorageFile>();
}

private async Task<List<StorageFile>> GetFiles(StorageFolder folder)
{
     var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();          
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
         if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
             files.Add(item);
         else
             await GetFiles(item as StorageFolder);
     }

     return files;
}


private async void GetFilesBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // opening folder picker, then selecting a folder
     var files = await GetFiles(folder);    
     // process files
     ProcessFiles(files);    
     // dispose
     DisposeFiles(files);
}
```

However, when working with large number of files, the memory consumption went really high (obviously).

So what came to mind is to use `yield return file` and process each file as it came, then once I'm done with that file I can dispose of it, and start working on the next file and so on.

What I've tried to do is this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> GetFiles(StorageFolder folder)
{
       var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();    
       foreach (var item in items)
       {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
                yield return item;
            else
               await GetFiles(item as StorageFolder);
       }
}
```

Then:

```
foreach (var file in GetFiles(folder))
{
      // process file
      ProcessFile(file);
      // dispose
      DisposeFile(file);
}
```

When doing this I'm getting:

> The body of 'GetFiles(StorageFolder)' cannot be an iterator block because Task IEnumerable StorageFile is not an iterator interface
>   type.

I've never used `yield return` before so I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: You need to look at reactive extensions (IObservable interface and related stuff). It can solve this problem in a nice way, and is just generally useful technique.

Answer (score 11):

As of C# 8, this can now be accomplished using [`IAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8).

You just need to change your return type from `Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>>` to `IAsyncEnumerable<StorageFile>`, then call the method using `await foreach` instead of `foreach`.

So your example will now look like this:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<StorageFile> GetFiles(StorageFolder folder)
{
       var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();    
       foreach (var item in items)
       {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
                yield return item;
            else
               await foreach (var item2 in GetFiles(item as StorageFolder))
                  yield return item2;
       }
}
```

Then:

```cs
await foreach (var file in GetFiles(folder))
{
      // process file
      ProcessFile(file);
      // dispose
      DisposeFile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You sure know how to make life difficult for yourself - async, yield and recursion! 
Unfortunately async/await and yield are not compatible in dotnet at the moment.

I would advise taking a different approach, instead of having your recursive function build up a list, pass it an action for it to apply to each file as it goes, something like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> ProcessFiles(StorageFolder folder, Action<StorageFile> process)
{
    var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();          
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
            process(item);
        else
           await ProcessFiles(item as StorageFolder);
    }
}

ProcessFiles(folder, file => {
    ProcessFile(file);
    DisposeFile(file);
});
```

You may wish to make ProcessFile and DisposeFile asynchronous, in which case:

```
ProcessFiles(folder, async file => {
    await ProcessFile(file);
    await DisposeFile(file);
});
```

If you want to define your action separately, you do it like this:

```
Action<StorageFolder> processor = ProcessFiles(folder, async file => {
    await ProcessFile(file);
    await DisposeFile(file);
});

ProcessFiles(folder, processor);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `async` keyword tells C# compiler to rewrite the method as a state machine that works asynchronously (aka `Task`).

The `yield return` keyword tells C# compiler to rewrite the method as a state machine that generates results lazily (aka `Enumerator`).

What you're trying to do is to combine the two approaches which will make the C# compiler very sad as it is currently not able to decide how to generate both state machines from one method. There is an open issue to support this feature in C# at dotnet/csharplang: [Champion "Async Streams" (including async disposable)](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43)

There is however a different approach you can use, `Task.WhenAll`, described in this question: [Is it possible to "await yield return DoSomethingAsync()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061761/is-it-possible-to-await-yield-return-dosomethingasync)

Note that the `Task.WhenAll` will resolve all the intermediate results into memory so you might end up with solution that is more complex and more memory-consuming than your original if you're not careful.

Next, you also have a bug in your code:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
        yield return item;
    else
        await GetFiles(item as StorageFolder); // <---- no return here
}
```

In the `else` branch, you do not return the retrieved value. So even if that code compiled, you would soon find out that it's not working correctly.

However, if you added the `return`, your method would need to both generate a state machine for `StorageFile` but also return the entire sequence in case of `StorageFolder`. This is not possible and you would need to take a different approach called flattening, simply by putting another `foreach` (note that the asynchronicity was removed for simplicity):

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
    else
    {
       foreach (var file in GetFiles(item as StorageFolder))
       {
           yield return file;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect opportunity to go [Reactive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx)!

I created this simple program, which you can easily edit to use StorageFolder and StorageFile instead of string as path:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            GetFilesFromDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).Subscribe(
                file =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                });


            var files = await GetFilesFromDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))
                .ToArray(); // you can also do this

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }).Wait();
    }


    static IObservable<string> GetFilesFromDirectory(string path)
    {
         var files = new Subject<string>();
        var directories = new Subject<string>();

        directories.Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x)).Subscribe(dir =>
        {
            foreach (var fileInfo in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                files.OnNext(fileInfo.FullName);
            }

            foreach (var directoryInfo in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                directories.OnNext(directoryInfo.FullName);
            }
        }, () =>
        {
            files.OnCompleted();
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            directories.OnNext(path);
            directories.OnCompleted();
        });

        return files;
    }
```

There is also an overload to [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) which does recursive search for you:

`var fileList = new DirectoryInfo(sDir).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat similar example of using yield. Basically replace GetRandomStringWDelayAsync with your GetFile code. Locking is not really necessary.

```
        object lockObj = new object();

        for (int i = 0; i < callCount; i++)
        {
            int j = i; // because of scope we can't use "i"  

            yield return Task.Run(async delegate {
                var pair = await StringService.RandomValues.GetRandomStringWDelayAsync(j);

                if (pair.Value != null)
                {
                    lock (lockObj)
                        dictionary[j] = pair.Value;
                }
            });
        }
```

full code here: https://github.com/sergeklokov/AsynchronousTasksDemo

Answer (score -1):

Because `yield` supports methods that their return type is `IEnumerable<T>` and `GetFiles()` returns `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` 
Check out this:

```
    public IEnumerable<StorageFile> GetFiles(StorageFolder folder)
    {
        // your code here
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> GetFilesAsync(StorageFolder folder)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => GetFiles(folder));
    }
```

And then you can do 
`foreach (var file in GetFiles(folder))` or `foreach (var file in await GetFilesAsync(folder))`

Edit:
Ah, your talking about IAsyncEnumerable which is not exist in the date you posted the answer

Comment: This will only await once and will not work with yield.